# Is it possible to control the visibility of the browser window scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We can affect the scroll bar of an HTML element through the `overflow` CSS property.

Is it possible to affect the scroll bar of the browser window?

Motivation - I am resizing HTML elements in code when the window is resized. During the resize two scroll bars are visible - the one of the window and the one of the particular HTML element. When the resizing ends only one scroll bar remains - that of the element, so everything is fine. But during the resize it looks ugly.

You can see it here - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/DaYCa/9/:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible -- just use [`body { overflow: hidden; }`](http://jsfiddle.net/6CvE4/).  You can test it out easily on this page from Firebug by running `$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");`.